# Is that possible to change swipe.js svg arrow images?

Tags: vue.js, slider, swiper.js

Im trying to change swipe.js arrow button images to another svg image. 
I have found actual path to svg in swiper.scss file

```
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  left: 10px;
  right: auto;
}
```

But when I'm trying to re-write the path  it does not change.Any ideas ?

```
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("@/assets/svg/arrow.svg");

}
```

Comment: is it possible that your image path is wrong ? otherwise it looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in my case (swiper@8) but it's not svg but png (but it should work with svg) :

```
.swiper {
    .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        &:after {
            content:'';
        }
    }
    .swiper-button-prev {
        background-image: url(../images/arrow-left.png);    
    }
    .swiper-button-next {
        background-image: url(../images/arrow-right.png);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, yo should to use !important in the css rule declaration.